# Cannot create two-dimensional unordered_map with user-defined class as key

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

As stated in the title, I am having trouble getting the VC++ compiler to work when using a two-dimensional map with a user-defined class as a key.
Here is the map I am trying to declare:

```
std::unordered_map<tag, std::map<tag, std::pair<bool, bool>>> transitRights;
```

And here are the declarations of class tag and the specialisation of the std::hash function:

```
class tag
{
public:
    tag();
    tag(const char[3]);
    tag(const std::string&);
    void operator=(const tag&);
    const bool operator==(const tag&)const;
    operator const std::string()const;
    const char& getA()const { return a; }
    const char& getB()const { return b; }
    const char& getC()const { return c; }
private:
    char a, b, c;
};


namespace std
{
    template<> class hash<tag>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const tag& _tag) const
        {
            return hash<char>()(_tag.getA()) ^ hash<char>()(_tag.getB()) ^ hash<char>()(_tag.getC());
        }
    };
};
```

When attempting to compile, Visual Studio throws a bunch of these cryptic error messages at me:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(600): error C2664: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const tag' to 'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const tag' to 'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,const tag&>(_Objty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,const tag&>(_Objty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(872) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const tag&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>  ,            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(872) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const tag&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>  ,            _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(933) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,const tag&>(_Ty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(933) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,const tag&>(_Ty *,const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1176) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree_buy<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>::_Buynode<const tag&>(const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree(1176) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,void *> *std::_Tree_buy<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>::_Buynode<const tag&>(const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>          ]
1>          nation.cpp(600) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<const tag&>(const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<int>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
1>          nation.cpp(600) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<const tag&>(const tag &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::pair<bool,bool>
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<int>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const int,std::pair<bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
```

Any insight into what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the nested object is a `std::map` (not an `unordered_map`) and for that you need a less-than comparison for `tag`.

You should be able to build an `unordered_map` of `unordered_map`s, however.

Answer (score 1):

The hash must be a `struct`:

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<tag> {
               ^^^^^^
    public:
        size_t operator()(const tag& _tag) const {
            return hash<char>()(_tag.getA()) ^ hash<char>()(_tag.getB()) ^ hash<char>()(_tag.getC());
        }
    };
};
```

Edit:

As [@6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) correctly mentioned, you will also have to define a less than `operator<` because you're using also a `std::map` with key `tag` (example below):

```
bool operator<(tag const &t1, tag const &t2) {
  return t1.getA() < t2.getA();    
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d28d02d5048f588)

Comment: The code will compile only if you don't actually use the `transitRights` object but will stop working as soon as you try to use it unless you make it an `unorederd_map<tag, unordered_map<...` instead of using `map` for the outer map value.

Comment: @StefanDimitrov `std::map` is an ordered container and needs to know how `tag` objects compare with each other in order to attain that order. However, you'll also have to change from `class` to `struct` as shown.